# Can this two recursive functions be merged into one?

Tags: arrays, c, sorting

```
    int sorted_a(int arr[], int N)
    {

        if (N == 1 || N == 0)
            return 1;
        if (arr[N - 1] < arr[N - 2])
        {
            return 0;
        }

        return sorted_a(arr, N - 1);
    }

    int sorted_d(int arr[], int N)
    {

        if (N == 1 || N == 0)
            return 1;
        if (arr[N - 1] > arr[N - 2])
        {
            return 0;
        }

        return sorted_d(arr, N - 1);
    }
```

These are two separate recursive functions to check if an array is sorted in ascending or descending order(they return one for each case), I can not seem to find a way to use only one to do the job(The function must return 1 only if it is sorted no matter the order(ascending or descending )). Any help ?

**Edit:**
Maybe my question wasn't clear enough. I just wanted to create one question that returns 1 only if the array is sorted(no matter the direction of sorting ascending / descending) and else returns 0.

Comment: `int sorted(int arr[], int N, int direction);` ... `sorted(a, 10, -1)` equivalent to `sorted_d(a, 10)`

Comment: And what do you mean by this

Comment: If you want a multi-algorithm function, you need to provide a mechanic for specifying the algorithm choice to the code within (either by argument or, hideously, by other means like a global). But I suspect that doesn't answer your question because I'm not convinced you are clear in what you're asking. You said, "I can not seem to find a way to use only one to do the job." Um... "the job" ?? We read that as you asking how to make a function that can do *either* on request. (hence a way to specify *which* as a function argument). If that isn't the case, you need to clarify your question.

Comment: Why do it using recursive functions?

Comment: @4386427 - what could possibly go wrong? :-)

Answer (score 1):

Since most of the solutions only handle ascending/descending one at a time or seem overly complex to me, here is a [non-recursive] version that tests for ascending/descending in a single pass in a single function:

```
int
sorted(const int *arr,int N)
{
    int sorted = 0x03;

    do {
        if (N < 2)
            break;

        int prev = arr[0];
        int cur;

        for (int idx = 1;  idx < N;  ++idx, prev = cur) {
            cur = arr[idx];

            // get difference
            int dif = cur - prev;

            // the same -- no change in state
            if (dif == 0)
                continue;

            // one of the sort directions is [now] wrong
            if (dif < 0)
                sorted &= 0x01;
            else
                sorted &= 0x02;

            // both directions are unsorted -- stop early
            if (! sorted)
                break;
        }
    } while (0);

    return sorted;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The task, i.e. check if an array is sorted, is not a task to be solved using recursive functions. Use simple `for/while` loops instead.

Further - why spend time on merging two functions into one? Good programming is actually about seperating stuff into simple functions. You already have two simple functions so you can just do:

```
int sorted(int arr[], int N)
{
    return sorted_a(arr, N) || sorted_d(arr, N);
}
```

That said, there are cases where it make sense (for performance and/or resource usage) to have a single "more complex" function instead of a number of simple functions. That does however not apply here as the approach (i.e. recursive functions) is wrong from the start.

Anyway - your two functions can be merged but the resulting **code is real bad**.

Here is an example but **DON'T DO IT LIKE THIS**

```
int sorted(int* arr, int N)
{

    if (N < 2) return 1;
    if (arr[0] == arr[1]) return sorted(arr+1, N - 1);
    
    if (arr[0] > arr[1])
    {
        if (arr[N - 1] > arr[N - 2])
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (arr[N - 1] < arr[N - 2])
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    return sorted(arr, N - 1);
}
```

Use `for/while` instead of recursion.

Answer (score 0):

A straightforward approach is to add one more parameter to the function that will specify the order in which the array is checked to be sorted.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int sorted( const int a[], size_t n, int ascending )
{
    return n < 2 || ( ( ascending ? !( a[1] < a[0] ) : !( a[0] < a[1]) ) &&
                        sorted( a + 1, n - 1, ascending   ) );
    
}

int main(void) 
{
    int a[] = { 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3 };
    size_t n = sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a );
    
    printf( "a[] is sorted - %s\n", sorted( a, n, 1 ) ? "true" : "false" );

    int b[] = { 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1 };
    n = sizeof( b ) / sizeof( *b );
    
    printf( "b[] is sorted - %s\n", sorted( b, n, 0 ) ? "true" : "false" );

    int c[] = { 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2 };
    n = sizeof( c ) / sizeof( *c );
    
    printf( "c[] is sorted - %s\n", sorted( c, n, 1 ) ? "true" : "false" );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
a[] is sorted - true
b[] is sorted - true
c[] is sorted - false
```

Comment: What if the array gets its values from the user?

Comment: @MemeGod And what? What is the problem?

Comment: Well it works but you'll need to call it twice to check "if it is sorted no matter the order(ascending or descending ))" so it's not that different from having two functions

Comment: @4386427 Yes, you need.

Answer (score 0):

First, convert the original functions into loops to get rid of the recursion. E.g. the first one would be:

```
int sorted_a(int arr[], int N) {
    while(N > 1) {
        if (arr[N - 1] < arr[N - 2]) {
            return 0;
        }
        N--;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Next; add 2 flags, one for "still possibly ascending" and another for "still possibly descending", so you can merge everything into a single function:

```
int sorted(int arr[], int N) {
    int a = 1;
    int d = 1;

    while(N > 1) {
        if( a != 0) {
            /* Still possibly ascending */
            if (arr[N - 1] < arr[N - 2]) {
                if( d != 0) {
                    /* Not ascending and can't be descending */
                    return 0;
                }
                a = 0;   /* Not ascending (but could still be descending) */
            }
        }
        if( d != 0) {
            /* Still possibly descending */
            if (arr[N - 1] > arr[N - 2]) {
                if( a != 0) {
                    /* Not descending and can't be ascending */
                    return 0;
                }
                d = 0;   /* Not descending (but could still be ascending) */
            }
        }
        N--;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

This version is likely slower than just having 2 separate versions (except for unlikely cases - e.g. when the array begins with the same number repeated a lot, like `{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, ...` continuing until it's larger than the cache). Despite this, it's a viable answer to your questions ("Yes, they can be merged!").

However; inside the loop there's only 3 cases (still possibly ascending or descending, still possibly ascending but not descending, and still possibly descending and not ascending). This means you could split the merged version into 3 parts to avoid some (`if(a == 0)`) branches, and get rid of the flags too, like:

```
int sorted(int arr[], int N) {
    if(N < 2) {
        return 1;
    }
    while(N > 1) {
        if (arr[N - 1] != arr[N - 2]) {
            if (arr[N - 1] > arr[N - 2]) {
                return sorted_a(arr, N-1);
            } else {
                return sorted_d(arr, N-1);
            }
        }
        N--;
    }
    return 1;
}

int sorted_a(int arr[], int N) {
    while(N > 1) {
        if (arr[N - 1] < arr[N - 2]) {
            return 0;
        }
        N--;
    }
    return 1;
}

int sorted_d(int arr[], int N) {
    while(N > 1) {
        if (arr[N - 1] > arr[N - 2]) {
            return 0;
        }
        N--;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

This is the fastest I can think of (but I don't think "merged when it helps performance but not merged when it hurts performance" is what you asked for, so..).