# C program checking if an array is sorted or not using a recursive function

Tags: arrays, c

```
            int sorted(int arr[], int N)
            {
                if (N == 1 || N == 0)
                    return 1;

                if (arr[N - 1] > arr[N - 2])
                {
                    if (arr[N - 1] < arr[N - 2])
                    {
                        return 0;
                    }
                }

                else
                {
                    return sorted(arr, N - 1);
                }

            }
```

I am having some trouble with the output. I can not tell if my logic is wrong or if there is something wrong with my code. The basic idea behind this piece of code is to return 1 if the array is sorted and 0 if not. Meanwhile my output is not what I was hoping for. This is a c exercise that I am doing to help me better understand the logic of recursive functions.

n-number of elements = 5 for testing sake.
**First input :** array[5,4,3,2,1] (sorted in descending order must return 1)
**Output :** *1*

**Second input :** array[1,2,3,4,5](sorted in descending order must return 1)
**Output :** *4*

**Third input :** array[2,1,5,3,8](not sorted, must return 0)
**Output :** *3*

Comment: Your tests return zero only if the last elements are in neither ascending order nor descending order. In other words, only if they are equal. If they are unequal, the function calls itself recursively. In doing so, it passes no information about which order the last two elements are in. There is no way for this function to ensure all elements are in the same order. You need to redesign the function. Think about how you can ask, first, “Which order might the elements of this array be in, ascending or descending?”, and, second, “Are the elements of this array in the selected order?”

Comment: Also, what is the function supposed to do if there are equal elements? Is [1, 2, 2, 3] is ascending order? (Mathematicians say it is in strictly ascending order if every element is greater than the previous one but it is in non-strictly ascending order if every element is greater than or equal to the previous one.)

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but you are basically saying that there is no way "this" function can check itself if it is sorted in ascending or descending order, it can only be determined by a parameter to "make the function know the exact order " .

Comment: It's pretty easy: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68691663/4386427

Comment: @EricPostpischil `[1, 2, 2, 3]`  is *sorted*, whatever mathematicians might say about it.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem.: When there is a discrepancy between code or its specification and language, you do not assume a resolution. You inquire and clarify. Failing to resolve such issues is a source of bugs.